Extra space in figure referencing with class file for Wiley NJD Journals
based on this template, using Overleaf, I can't figure out how to remove the space after I reference a figure.
No matter what I try, it will compile to "
sample text to reference a figure (Fig. 1 ). As seen in Figure 2 a and Figure 2 b."
The goal is "
sample text to reference a figure (Fig. 1). As seen in Figure 2A and Figure 2B."
\documentclass[STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subparens}{[\Alph{subfigure}]}
\captionsetup[sub]{
  labelformat=subparens, 
  position=top,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  skip = -0.25cm,
  font=normalsize}

\begin{document}

Preferred Figure Setup
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{% 
        \label{fig:testsub1}
        \hspace{.4cm}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Pictures/test.png}}
    \hspace{1cm} 
    \subfloat[]{%
        \label{fig:testsub2}\hspace{.4cm}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Pictures/test.png}} 
    \caption{test caption\label{F2}}     
\end{figure}
    
Alternative Figure setup
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Pictures/test.png}    
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Pictures/test.png}    
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main Figure Caption}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}    

Figure setup from template
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Pictures/test.png}
\caption{Figure caption\label{F6}}
\end{figure}

sample text to reference a figure (Fig. \ref{F2}). As seen in Figure~\ref{fig:sub1} and Figure~\ref{fig:sub2}. 
sample text to reference a figure (Fig.~\ref{F2}). As seen in Figure~\ref{fig:sub1} and Figure~\ref{fig:sub2}.


\end{document}

